# easySlider plugin text not hiding on scroll out

Tags: jquery, easyslider

easySlider 1.7 jQuery plugin (viewable at http://www.lunchboxbill.co.uk/) when animating hides the image fine, but not the `<span>` text also used within the `<a>` for the title.

Have I missed something really obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a position: relative inside your slider, and then you can adjust the slider a span to have top:0 instead of top:11 and it will fix it for you.

```
#slider {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 }

 #slider a span {
 background-color: #999999;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 opacity: 0.4;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 558px;
 }
```